# Is there a way to intercept the raw data that's being sent over a WCF endpoint?

Tags: wcf, performance

Is there a way to intercept the raw data that's being sent over a TCP WCF endpoint? I have implemented IClientMessageInspector but I am not sure if that's what's actually being sent over the wire.
My goal is to measure the performance of different serializers. I know there is some information out there but I would like to take a closer look at how they behave in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable [Message Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731859.aspx) in your configuration. To see the raw messag you want to log at Transport level.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into the built-in tracing capabilities of WCF. I don't have a link handy, but search for WCF tracing.

Comment: rua marcos macedo 1255 apto 1255 Aldeota CEP 60150190 Fortaleza CE